# Javah missing android.os.Parcelable

Tags: android, header, java-native-interface, javah

When I'm trying to create a headerfile with javah I get an error that he can't find the Parcelable class.

Before I created the header with:

**From %PROJECTDIR%/bin/classes/**

```
javah -classpath com.my.project
```

But now I added the Parcelable to the native calls I include the android.jar to the commandline call:
**From %PROJECTDIR%/bin/classes/**

```
javah -classpath :~/shared/android.jar:~/shared/MyProject/bin/classes com.my.project
```

I will get this error:

```
Error: Class android.os.Parcelable could not be found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem... I had one colon to many.

```
javah -classpath ~/shared/android.jar:. com.my.project
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message but a different problem (under Windoze). For some reason i had to quote the classpath although there was no whitespace in the path:

```
C:\myProjectPath>javah -jni -classpath "C:\Users\myUserName\android-sdks\platforms\android-15\android.jar";bin\classes -d jni package1.package2.myInterestingClass
```

And this didn't work:

```
C:\myProjectPath>javah -jni -classpath C:\Users\myUserName\android-sdks\platforms\android-15\android.jar;bin\classes -d jni package1.package2.myInterestingClass
```

And it worked when using a relative path:

```
C:\myProjectPath>javah -jni -classpath ..\..\..\..\..\Users\myUserName\android-sdks\platforms\android-15\android.jar;bin\classes -d jni package1.package2.myInterestingClass
```

Spent a few hours on this, windows is really weird most of the time. Maybe this helps someone else.